# Redirecting non www version of my site to www version results in a redirect loop

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I have my website at [http://www.artsplash.in](http://www.artsplash.in/) and i was trying to redirect non www version of my site to www version(and i dont know if my server is itself doing the reverse without my knowledge).
I already have the .htaccess file as

```
# DO NOT REMOVE THIS LINE AND THE LINES BELOW HOTLINKID:nunaquvaQe
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://artsplash.in/.*$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://artsplash.in$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://www.artsplash.in/.*$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://www.artsplash.in$      [NC]
RewriteRule .*\.(1)$ http://www.artsplash.in [R,NC]
# DO NOT REMOVE THIS LINE AND THE LINES ABOVE nunaquvaQe:HOTLINKID


# DO NOT REMOVE THIS LINE AND THE LINES BELOW REDIRECTID:anajuqehyv
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^artsplash.in$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.artsplash.in$
RewriteRule ^mail$ http://webmail1.nazuka.net/roundcube/ [R=301,L]
# DO NOT REMOVE THIS LINE AND THE LINES ABOVE anajuqehyv:REDIRECTID


# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^login$ wp-login.php
RewriteRule ^register$ wp-login.php?action=register
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Anything I did myself for redirecting to www.artsplash.in resulted in a browser message that site has a redirection loop. What exactly should I add to my .htaccess file to get desired result?
-Need help badly.

Answer (score 0):

You Must Use This Code In htaccess File To Preferred www Version:

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(.).YourDomain.com$ [NC] RewriteRule ^(.)$ http://www.YourDomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

For Better S.E.O : 
You Could Setting Your Preferred Domain In Google Web Master Tools If Your Website Was Added In Google Webmaster Tools :

Open up your webmaster tools and click “Settings” right below “Configuration”. To the right look for the “Preferred Domain” and select which domain you prefer With www Or Not.